# On an affine analogue of the fact $\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{g}]^G$ is a polynomial ring

Tags: rt.representation-theory

I'd like to ask if the following "analogue" of the fact $\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{g}]^G$ for semisimple $G$ is a polynomial ring is known, or disproved, or anything.

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a simple Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\mathfrak{g}[[t]]=g\otimes \mathbb{C}[[t]]$, similarly for $\mathfrak{g}((t))$. Pick a nilpotent orbit $O$ of $\mathfrak{g}$, and consider a subset of $\mathfrak{g}((t))$ of the form

> $X_O= \{n/t + x \ |\ n\in \overline{O}, \, x\in \mathfrak{g}[[t]]\} $.`

$\mathfrak{g}[[t]]$ acts naturally on $X_O$. I'd like to know if $R=\mathbb{C}[X_O]^{\mathfrak{g}[[t]]}$ is a polynomial ring. More precisely:

Functions on $X_O$ are generated by coordinate functions $a_i:X_O\to \mathbb{C}$ which is defined for $a\in \mathfrak{g}^*$ and $i\in\mathbb{Z}$ via $a_i(y)=$ ($a$ applied on the coefficient of $t^i$ of $y\in X_O$). We assign bidegree $(1,i)$ to $a_i$.

Then, I'm interested in the subring $R_-$ of $R$ whose second degree is negative. I think $R_-$ is a polynomial ring generated by $(\dim O)/2$ variables. I'd like to know the bidegree of the generators, too.

(One might need to require $\mathfrak{g}$ to be simply-laced, and/or $O$ to be special.)

For example, when $O$ is the orbit of zero, $R_-$ is just $\mathbb{C}$.

When $O$ is the regular nilpotent orbit, $R_-$ has $\dim O/2$ generators $c_{k,i}$ where $k=1,\ldots,\mathrm{rank}\, \mathfrak{g}$ and $i=1,\ldots, e_k$  where $e_k$ is the $k$-th exponent of $\mathfrak{g}$. Explicitly, $c_{k,i}$ is given as follows: denote by $c_k\in \mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{g}^*]^G$ a generator of degree $e_k+1$. Then we can consider  $c_k(y)\in \mathbb{C}((t))$.
 for $y\in \mathfrak{g}((t))$. Finally we can define $c_{k,i}:X_O\to \mathbb{C}$  as the coefficient of $t^{-i}$ of $c_k(y)$ where $y\in X_O$.

Comment: are you sure you want to consider invariant of g[[t]] ? I mean, may be just taking Gaudin-Bethe commutative subalgebra is what you want ? Cause if starting with first sentence analogy C[g]^C - polynomial ring  - it is center of U(g), but in loop algebra case U(g(t)) has center, not U(g[t]) (modula details like crit. level etc.) - the correct analog of "center" in positive loops U(g[t]) is very simple thing - called Gaudin-Bethe commutative subalgebra in U(g[t]) - it is just image of the projection of Center(U((g (t)) under projection g(t)->g[t]. It is free polynomial and as nice as possible:)

Comment: Hmm, maybe what I want is $\mathbb{C}[Ad \mathfrak{g}((t)) X_O ]^{\mathfrak{g}((t))}$. Does it make a difference? I'd like to know how the invariant rings depend on the nilpotent residue chosen. 

Anyway thank you for the suggestion... I'll study Gaudin-Bethe commutative subalgebras.

Comment: If I am not making mistake, it makes big difference. I think that properly understood invariants in affine case should behave the same as in non-affine. 


Comment: Some remarks: on U(g(t)) has two products - standard one and "normal ordered". The center in standard product is commutative subalgebra in normal ordered (Guadin-Bethe). Normal ordering means that positive loops commute with negative loops - means that U(g(t))^{normal product} = U(g[t]) \otimes U(g[t^-1]) , so there is natural projections which are algebra homorphisms U(g(t))^{normal product} -> U(positve loops) or to negative loops. So the center becomes commutative subalgebras in positve (negative) loops.

Comment: If one considers "classical limit" e.g. with Poisson brackets, but not commutators, then the explicit formula for the center(and GaudinBethe) is det(L(z) - l ) = C_{ij}z^il^j , C_{ij} will be free generators (it is very simple).
The beautiful discovery by Dmitry Talalaev is that that in quantum case the correct formula looks like det(d/dz - L(z)) = C_{ij}z^i (d/dz)^j - so we get differential operator - it is what is called GL_n-oper in the Langlands correspondence theory, see e.g. section 8.2 page 30 in http://arxiv.org/abs/0711.2236 as well as http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0604128

Comment: Thanks for the references. Yes what I'm looking for is related to Gaudin systems / opers, but I'd like to know what happens when the oper has a singularity at $z=0$, with nilpotent residue. I guess what you're talking about is the case when the oper is smooth at $z=0$.

Comment: For example, in E. Frenkel's book "Langlands correspondence for loop groups", opers with a regular nilpotent residue is studied; indeed it's an affine space (see (9.2.13)). I'd like to know what happens if the residue is in (the closure of) a given nilpotent orbit. (I'm not saying this question and the question posed above are (proven to be) mathematically equivalent; it's just that possible math formulations of my physics question can be either.)

Comment: For Talalaev's formula there is completely NO difference regular-irregular, reside is nilpotent or semisimple... In all cases you get commutative subalgebra in U(gl[t]), if residue is semisimple - it "constant magnetic field" (all spins in the same magnetic field) and Gaudin's hamiltonians are semisimple in spin representation, if residue is nilpotent than Gaudin's hamiltonians acting in spin represenation become something like 'creation operator' (I am not sure Leonya Rybnikov worked on this some time ago)... But it is difference in representation; on the level of algebras - no difference

Comment: PS. And on the level of "opers" - no difference between regular-irregular/nilpotent-semisimple 

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. The smooth oper (on a disk) and the nilpotent oper (on a disk) are surely different. Compare (4.2.9) and (9.2.13) of http://www.msri.org/people/staff/levy/files/forEdik.pdf

Comment: In your notation, my whole question is about the determination of the structure of $C_{ij}$ for negative $i$. 

Comment: Talalaev's formula works for all $i \in Z$ (i.e. ALL integers - both positive and negative).
It states that defining $:det(d/dz- L(z)): = (d/dz)^n+ \sum_{i\in Z, j=0...n-1} C_{ij} z^i \partial_z^j$ , then $C_{ij}$ are free generators on the center on the critical level. 

Comment: Thank You for the reference ! I looked, but I am cannot understand this fast and relate to Talalaev's approach.


Comment: In case if it is of some help, there are papers by A. Molev, where he generalized Talalaev's approach to super-gl and B-C-D: http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.2341  http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.3447 - so there is super analogue of oper which as easy to guess given by : $:Berezianian( \partial_z -L(z)):$ , but it B-C-D case result is more involved - Brauer algebra is used - I was unable to guess this solution for several years... PS Also about gl case there is our paper with Molev which uses VOA to obtain self-contained proof for Talalaev's type formula: http://arxiv.org/abs/0808.1947

Comment: Then I think what I'd like to study is different from what you suggest, see my edit above. I need to impose a condition on the pole of your $L(z)$, that it has at most a pole of first order, and the residue is in the nilpotent orbit $O$ I specify. This condition then forces $C_{ij}$ for sufficiently negative $j$ to vanish, say $j<s(O,i)$. I'd like to know $s(O,i)$, for example. 

Comment: some time to think:) But I do not quite understand. "L(z)" is first order pole at z=0 or at what point ? "Negative $j$" - but you said that it is "only first order pole" - seems contradiction - if negative j than poles may be non first order ?

Comment: For example for gl_2 what kind of L(z) you consider ?  there is "full" $L(z)_{ij} = \sum_{i \in Z} (e_{ij}t^i/z^{i+1} )$ .  Now what you say ? $i>0$ or $i<0$  ?

Comment: $L(z)$ has only a first order pole. But $det(x−L(z))$ can have higher poles (up to order n), right? For gln, $L(z)=N/z+...$ where $N$ has a given Jordan form. Your $L(z)$ is an element in $X_O$ in my question. Your $z$ is my $t$.

Comment: Yes, you right. 
I begin to understand...
So you say if consider gl_n and  regular nilpotent orbit - then dim O  is of the size n^2-n and it is the same 2*(1+...+n-1). 